# Why are the options in my UIAlertController dim and how can I fix it?

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

This is a weird one. I'm making a UIAlertController with the following code:

```
let optionMenu = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Choose Option", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 1", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })

    let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Action 2", style: .Default, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: {
        (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in
        print("Cancelled")
    })

    optionMenu.addAction(cancelAction)
    optionMenu.addAction(action)
    optionMenu.addAction(action2)

    self.presentViewController(optionMenu, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And here's what it looks like on screen. The options are dim (I believe pulling in or being affected by the rear views).

[Dimmed Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7iG8G.png)

I was able to add this code to make it pure white, but the nice-ness of the separation goes away.

```
let subview = optionMenu.view.subviews.first! as UIView
let alertContentView = subview.subviews.first! as UIView
alertContentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
alertContentView.layer.cornerRadius = 2
```

And it looks like this: [Non-dimmed, but not quite right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBvBA.png)

Any ideas on how to not let the background affect the options in the UIAlertController?

I added this UIAlertController to a page with a white background and it looked like it should.

Thanks!

Comment: And you're able to select the dimmed rows? Have you made any global changes to appearance of any elements using UIAppearance anywhere?

Comment: Hi @shim I can select the rows. I believe matt below is right, but I still would like to know how to make them not translucent, and still retain their original shapes.

Comment: I'm having this same issue; as a side note, you can simply use optionMenu.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor() to get your second image, no need to dig around in the views.  It overrides the default shapes still, I'm still not sure how to retain them and go to non-transparent white.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug. Nothing is "dimmed". The alert buttons are translucent, so they are darker over a dark background. They are also reddish over a red background and bluish over a blue background; that's what translucent means. All action sheets in all apps look like this. There's no problem here. Don't worry, be happy.

Comment: Even if some people would prefer this appearance, there's plenty of people who would rather all of the buttons be the same exact color/transparency.  Cancel being fully white and all other actions somewhat grayish isn't what my design is asking for...

Comment: @Tasonir Then don't use UIAlertController. It doesn't do anything you can't do yourself. And you can do _whatever you like_ if you just use a custom presented view controller.

Answer (score 0):

This is my objective c code. Try the swift counterpart for the same :

```
[alert.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

Hope it helps!